# Opening DFP Advertisements in browser window

Tags: mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

I am able to get Google DFP ads to display in my Sencha Touch app, but when I click on these advertisements the link opens up inside of the app, making the app unusable because it is now a webpage. Is there anyway I can force the app to use the browser or an in app browser? Google DFP uses Iframes, which I am assuming can complicate things.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using a script like this, It alters the hrefs inside of the iframe to point to the goto function, which opens the url with the InAppBrowser. But the inappbrowser must first be added to the project, which I describe below.

```
function goto(url){
    var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
}

window.onload = function() {
    var link = window.frames['iframeName'].document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(i=0;i<link.length;i++) {
        link[i].href="javascript:window.top.goto('"+link[i].href+"');";
    }
}
```

I also had to follow the simple directions in the Accessing the Feature, section of the InAppBrowser documentation, located here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Answer (score 0):

@EvWill's answer will work for adverts which are just images. It won't work when the adverts are HTML5 as the `hrefs` can be in multiple locations or may be opened with Javascript.

In this case you can't intercept the loading to direct it to an InAppBrowser or native browser.

One work around is to use the AdMob plugin which supports DFP https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

But this has it's limitations too as you can only display adverts in certain locations. They are overlayed on your app instead of embedded into it (so you can't have an advert scroll inline with your content)